# How to define flow.js output type based on input type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm new to flow.js, and I've a rather simple question: 
Let's say I have a function taking either type A or type B as an input, and returns type AA if input is A, or BB is input is B :

```
type A = {|a: string|}
type B = {|b: string|}
type AA = {|aa: string|}
type BB = {|bb: string|}
const f = (x: A | B, type: string): AA | BB => type === "A" ? {aa: "AA"}: {bb: "BB"}
```

My problem is I can't do that:

```
const x: A = {a: "x"}
const y: AA = f(x, "A")
```

y needs to be type AA | BB

I tried to use parameterized generics like

```
type C<T> = typeof(T) === "A" ? AA : BB;
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you'd want to have multiple declarations of your function.

[Here's an example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAfAhgLigZ2AJwEsA7AcxQF8AoUSKAIQWRQCMtdDSLrxoY5FUaTDnzEyVGtDoMBLViI7jKlACYQAxgBs0eaADMArkXXACAeyJQ9ACgAeWGABooktqNIBKBzFUbtuqyMTc0sbe3pnVwUxL3o6ZXULXCg0ImwARm9GGyQUrAByYAhcfKhyZ3yYfI9KAHpaqAASAFFbSBNmvDwzPEpEtOAUtIAmLGls61zhQuLgUvKoSuqEpMHU7ABmMZkrSah5GZKyirpl+qbW9uBO7t7+5PWAFizEHP2CoqOF-NOPIA)

```
declare function f(x: A, type: string): AA
declare function f(x: B, type: string): BB
```

Now, if you were going to make this return based on the `type` argument, you could specify that as a literal (`'A'`, etc) if you wanted and it would also check that. For example:

```
declare function f(x: A, type: 'A'): AA
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into that. I've just tried to add the actual implementation (with types) on your snippet, and I can't make it work using arrow functions, is there a way to do it?  I can use regular (/old) syntax, but I'd really prefer to use arrows

Comment: Here's an issue detailing why arrow functions won't work at this time: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2059